# Is it possible to create a T-SQL function that returns either a varchar() or nvarchar() depending on some database or table characteristic?

Tags: function, t-sql, sql-server-2012, output

I see similar questions for Javascript and other languages, but I work in T-SQL.

I have a function that removes non-alpha characters from a string and the output is varchar().   I would like a similar function to do the same but output in nvarchar() to prevent implicit conversions when I am dealing with nvarchar() data.

I know I could simply have two functions and call the appropriate one when needed, but for backwards compatibility, it would be nice to have a single function that could check the table being updated, or something along those lines, and output the appropriate varchar() or nvarchar() string.  Then I could universally replace all occurrences of this function with the single 'one-size-fits-all' function.

Has anybody ever seen or come up with something like this, or is this simply too much to ask of a function, and I should consider using a stored procedure?

Comment: No. You would need to pick a single type that can hold all your values. `nvarchar` in this case. You could also use [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but that would hardly be better, unless you are only going to call this function from multistep code that is happy to be checking for its [`SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(BaseType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Aside: A [CLR scalar-valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-ver15#requirements-for-clr-scalar-valued-functions) wouldn't help: "The input parameters and the type returned from a SVF can be any of the scalar data types supported by SQL Server, except `varchar`, `char`, `rowversion`, `text`, `ntext`, `image`, `timestamp`, `table`, or `cursor`."